# Copying between two canvas causes blur

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two canvases. When I use `drawImage()` to copy from one canvas to the other, it is blurring the image slightly.

Why is this happening?

This seems like the kind of thing that occurs when theres some sub-pixel rounding. Maybe this is caused by the 45 degree 'rotation'?

Here is an example showing it occur:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("tmpCanvas");
var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
tempCanvas.width = canvas.width;
tempCanvas.height = canvas.height;

// translate origins
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
tempCtx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

// Create a red square
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0, 0.1)";
ctx.fillRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);

var angle = 0;

// Each draw we copy the current canvas to the tmpCanvas. Then copy it back to the original canvas.
function draw() {
  angle += 45;

  tempCtx.save();
  tempCtx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
  tempCtx.drawImage(
    canvas,
    0, // sourceX
    0, // sourceY - note that source ignores translation. It's not a canvas context, so we choose top left corner of the canvas to start copying pixels.
    canvas.width, // sourceWidth
    canvas.height, // sourceHeight
    -0.5 * canvas.width, // destinationX
    -0.5 * canvas.height, // destinationY
    canvas.width, // destinationWidth
    canvas.height // destinationHeight
  );
  tempCtx.restore();

  ctx.drawImage(
    tempCanvas,
    0,
    0,
    canvas.width,
    canvas.height,
    -0.5 * canvas.width,
    -0.5 * canvas.height,
    canvas.width,
    canvas.height
  );

  // requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

document.addEventListener("click", draw);
```

```css
canvas {
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
```

```html
<p>
Click to trigger a "draw".
<br/>
A draw will do this:<br/>
1. rotate the bottom canvas by 45 degrees.<br/>
2. copy the top canvas to the bottom canvas<br/>
3. copy the bottom canvas to the top canvas<br/>
</p>
<br/>
<p>
Clicking repeatedly will "blur" the squares. Why?
</p>
<br/>
</p>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="tmpCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas - seems like the kind of thing that can't be fixed. Any ideas?

Comment: My goal is to make a canvas where you can draw on it, as the existing contents rotate about the origin.

Comment: Turned my comments into a answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just antialiasing in action. When rotating twice by 45 degrees, the antialised edges fall slightly outside the original square, and these add up over time.

> My goal is to make a canvas where you can draw on it, as the existing contents rotate about the origin.

You can make the drawing actions happen on the original canvas (apply the inverse rotation to the position of the mouse), and then repeatedly draw the original canvas rotated to the output canvas. Data flows in just one direction, from the original to the output, so there's no degradation.

Comment: Thanks @thomas! That makes sense. Just want to check one last thing before I implement it. In the linked example, you get color distortion. I'm assuming this is also from anti-aliasing effects being exaggerated with each draw: https://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/EbKjZo

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it is. Possibly combined with accuracy loss due to use of premultiplied alpha.